# Spring @Transactional annotation with a transaction across multiple data sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've successfully made connection with 2 database, and I'm able to select, insert, update and delete from 1st db connection, but while using 2nd database I'm able to fetch the data but I'm not able to update or save any data in database.

This is my jpaContext.xml

Configuration for 1st database connection

```
<bean name="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mdmDriverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    name="factory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
   
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.bmp.mdm_v1.entites</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory" />
    <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory" />
</bean>
```

Configuration for 2nd database

```
<bean name="mdmDs" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${mdmDbUrl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mdmDbUsr}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mdmDbPass}" />
</bean>                        

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    name="mdmFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mdmDs" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
   
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.bmp.stamp_biller.entites</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
                   
<bean name="mdmTmp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mdmFactory" />
    <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="mdmTxnMang" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mdmFactory" />
</bean>
```

This  is my dao implementation

```
@Transactional
public void saveClientBiller(client_biller client_biller) {
    try {
        this.mdmTmp.saveOrUpdate(client_biller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception- " + e);
    }
}
```

The data is stored in database but I'm getting this error after saving data in 2nd db

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

I'm getting soultion that put @Transactional(value="mdmTxnMang"), but while I'm doing that it will show me error like string cannot be converted to txType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that yours import is

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Next step: Try to create 2 different TransactionManagers. Set one of them to transaction's property.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = MyFirstTM.class)
```

Comment: Step 1 implemented but I'm not able to get what is the second step. Could you show any reference code that makes it more clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey thanku I've just added this import import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;    @Transactional(value = "mdmTxnMang")        and this will solve my problem . Really thanku so much, I've been trying this for 5 days

Comment: Hey, glad to help you! Error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException` shows wrong package `javax`. I assumed `javax.transaction.Transactional` is being used instead of Spring @Transactional. Please mark as correct answer to help other developers.